# Django TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'model_name'

Tags: django, signals, typeerror

While coding a Django signal, I am getting a TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'model_name'. From the code, I expected to get the 'Payment_record' function triggered when a 'Payment' is made. Here is the code.

models.py

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    paid_by = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    student_name = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payable_towards = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices = payable_towards, default = "tuition_fee")
    payment_date =  models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    amount_paid = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=True)
    account_name = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=70)
    receipt_number = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=True, unique=True)
    name = models.ForeignKey(Staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="pay_received_by",)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.student_name)
```

```
# signal to add payment to account
```

```
class Payment_record(models.Model):
    payment_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    student_name = models.ForeignKey(Payment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="pay_date_record",)
    balance = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=True)
    # record_history =
    payment_status = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices = payment_status, default = "underpaid")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.student_name)
```

.....................................
apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class FinancesConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'finances'
    
    def ready(self):
        import finances.signals
```

......................................
signals.py

```
from .models import Payment_record, Payment
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Payment)
def create_payment_record(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Payment_record.objects.create(Payment=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Payment)
def save_payment_record(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.Payment_record.save
```

......................................

I have also attached the screenshots for the above code snippets.

What could be the problem and how do I solve it? Or better still, with the 2 models, how can I create the signal?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you work with a database router?

Comment: Shouldn't `Payment_record.objects.create(Payment=instance)` be `Payment_record.objects.create(student_name=instance)` in signals.py ?

Comment: It still doesn't work. I get the following: AttributeError at /admin/finances/payment/add/ 'Payment' object has no attribute 'Payment_record'   And no, I dont work with database router. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to your models it should be:

```
student_name = models.ForeignKey(Payment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="pay_date_record",)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Payment)
def create_payment_record(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Payment_record.objects.create(student_name=instance)
```

I think you have a problem with the name of the Payment ForeignKey field.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I get the following: AttributeError at /admin/finances/payment/add/ 'Payment' object has no attribute 'Payment_record' . Thank you.